# How do I create a url to reach docker service running on linux server

Tags: linux, docker, hosting

I want to expose a docker container running some service on port say X on a Linux server to be accessible using URL say http://< server_hostname> /< some_service> ? What should be the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by exposing your docker local port to your host machine

```
docker run -p hostport:containerport nginx
```

You can do for multiple ports too

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 5000:5000 nginx
```

Now you have http://localhost:port

you have multiple ways to add a domain in your machine

1. you can add URL by adding a domain to your host machine IP.
   it require your host machine IP port forwarding.
2. you can use https://ngrok.com for free IP to the domain without port forwarding.
3. also, you can do it locally by editing your machine host file

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your container port to host machine and then you can access that. Below is the example for `Nginx`

```
docker run -p 80:80 nginx
```

as `-p` exposes the container port `80` to Host port `80`. Then, you can access the service by hitting the `localhost:80` or `127.0.0.1:80` or `machineIP:80` on your browser

Comment: Well that is already done. But I want to access the service using some URL say hostname/service_name. So anyone can use that using this URL without providing port number

Comment: For that, you need to host a DNS server and get it added in to your DNS servers which will point it to the machineIP

Comment: The port number must be 443 for standard HTTP-over-TLS (or 80 for insecure plain HTTP).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a proxy server running in docker along with your services. Nginx, Apache, or Traefik can be set up for this. The idea would be that only the proxy actually has an exposed port, and it routes traffic where it needs to go on the internal Docker network based on the path.